# ¿Como Inhabilitar días específicos en input type date en net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando una aplicación en net core y tengo un input tipo `date`

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime FechaPresentarLaborar { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

¿Cúal seria la mejor manera para poder inhabilitar los días festivos en el input? o poder hacerlo con días específicos?
Se los agradecería mucho si pudieran guiarme.

Comment: Podrías construir tu propio validador, acá hay ejemplos de custom validators https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406046/data-annotation-ranges-of-dates

Comment: no estas haciendo una aplicacion en net core.. estas haciendo una aplicacion en C#